# Java - indicated update available but when clicked said already latest

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java

Does anyone has the same problem as me? I am not sure if Java has a update or not, but it keeps asking me to update daily, but when I click to update, it said I already has the latest update?!

My specs:
Windows 7 x64
Java installed x64 version 7 build 17 (build 1.7.0_17-b02)

Well, when I check on the site, there is 21 available already, but is there also a 21 update for 64 bits computer also??

Please help me solve my problem

Comment: Yes, The current version exists on all supported platforms.  Should be as simple as removing the current version you have installed and installed the current version from the Oracle website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_installshield.xml

Sorry, I fixed myself, I think I did not provide enough information when I tried to install it manually.